# Finding conditions for a with given condition for critical points

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

> $f(x)=\sin2x-8(a+1)\sin x+(4a^2+8a-14$)$x$. $x$ increases for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and has no critical points. Find values of $a$.

My try:
$f'(x)=4(\cos^2x-2(a+1)\cos x+a^2+2a-4)=0$
and $f''(x)=0$. And on solving i will get range of $a$. That's my answer. But answer doesn't match with original values of answer. Am i missing anthing?

Comment: If $f$ increases for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and has not critical points, then you should have $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Derivative of $sin2x$=2$cos2x$=2{2$cos^2x$-1}

Comment: If $$f(x) = \sin 2x - 8(a+1) \sin x + 4a^2 + 8a - 14,$$ then the derivative with respect to $x$ is $f'(x) = 2 \cos 2x - 8(a+1) \cos x$.  The terms $4a^2 + 8a - 14$ are **constant with respect to x**.

Comment: Now that you've edited the question, my previous comment is no longer applicable.  Next time, please be sure that when you ask a question, that it is posed *accurately*.

Comment: They aren't.Why are you saying that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f'($x$)=4[$\mathrm cos^2x$-2($a$+1)$cosx$+$a^2$+2$a$-4]
Let $\phi$($t$) = $t^2$-2($a$+1)$t$+$a^2$+2$a$-4. -1$\le$$t$$\le$1.
It is sufficient to find values of t when $\phi$($t$) = 0 has no roots in [-1,1].
Discriminant D = 20.
USING CONDITIONS FOR QUADRATIC EQUATIONS 
Case I:-     $\phi$(-1) $\gt$ 0.$a$+1 $\le$ -1.D=20.$a$ $\in$ (-$\infty$,-2-$\sqrt5$)$\cup$(-2+$\sqrt5$,+$\infty$) and $a$$\lt$-2.$\implies$ $a$ $\in$(-$\infty$,-2-$\sqrt5$).
Case II:-$\phi$(1) $\gt$ 0.$a$+1 $\gt$ 1.D=20.
$\implies$ $a$ $\in$ (-$\infty$,-$\sqrt5$) $\cup$ ($\sqrt5$,+$\infty$),$a$ $\gt$0 $\implies$ $a$ $\in$ ($\sqrt5$,+$\infty$).Hence final values of $a$ are $a$ $\in$ (-$\infty$,-2-$\sqrt5$) $\cup$ ($\sqrt5$,+$\infty$)

Comment: Not only is the derivative incorrect, your bizarre use of $\TeX$ formatting is almost incomprehensible.  I don't know why you formatted your response in such a way when it is much easier to type the entire expression within a single pair of dollar signs.

Comment: Well i'm new to this site.I don't know how to use this language properly

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** : I am afraid that your derivative is wrong. It is supposed to be  $$2 \cos (2 x)-8 (a+1) \cos (x)$$. Nox, since you are told that $f$ has no critical points, the derivative should not cancel for any $x$ and this will give conditions for $a$. For sure, you must expand $cos(2x)$ as a function of $cos(x)$ to get a quadratic equation.

I am sure you can take from here.

Comment: No.The derivative is correct $sin2x$=2$cos2x$=2{2$cos^2x$-1}

Comment: @DevgeetPatel. Where are the constants coming from in the posted derivative ?